# rJava gives a NullPointerException in .jcall

Tags: r, rjava, mallet

I am trying to run a standard corpus loading method in the `mallet` R package and more specifically

```
instance <- mallet.import(names(txt$CELEX), txt$TEXT, stoplist.file = "stopwords.en.txt", token.regexp = "\\p{L}[\\p{L}\\p{P}]+\\p{L}")
```

Then I get the following error

```
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

which seems to me more like an rJava error more than anything else. My sysinfo follows:

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)

Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Danish_Denmark.1252  LC_CTYPE=Danish_Denmark.1252    LC_MONETARY=Danish_Denmark.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Danish_Denmark.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] mallet_1.0           XLConnect_0.2-12     XLConnectJars_0.2-12 quanteda_0.9.6-9     rJava_0.9-8         
[6] topicmodels_0.2-4   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.5       lattice_0.20-33   slam_0.1-35       chron_2.3-47      grid_3.3.0        stats4_3.3.0     
 [7] stringi_1.1.1     data.table_1.9.6  NLP_0.1-9         ca_0.64           Matrix_1.2-6      tools_3.3.0      
[13] parallel_3.3.0    tm_0.6-2          modeltools_0.2-21
```

I use Java 8 in case it matters. I read somewhere that rJava is not playing well with Java 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the usual error from rJava problems, which seem to have settled down.

One possible problem could be that the stoplist file does not exist or is not in the right place.

Comment: Thanks David. You pointed me to the right direction. It was `names(txt$CELEX)` that was creating me the problem but I 'm not that good at R so I made a mistake. For the record, if I use `txt$CELEX` instead, it works fine! Hint to the community: make sure that you reinitialize your model with `MalletLDA` after import and before training